# I am not able to find Itext.text jar in the maven repository. Can you provide me link to download the jar?

Tags: java, maven, itext

I want to render charts in PDF using Itext amd JFreeChart library. 
I want to use PdfContentByte and PdfTemplate classes present in  com.itextpdf.text.pdf library. But I am not able to find this dependency in the maven repository. Can anyone provide me link to download this dependency, so that I can add it to my local maven repository.

Comment: Reason to downvote: there is a "download hub" page on the official iText web page: https://developers.itextpdf.com/downloads The official web site should be the first place to look for downloads and that would make the need to post a "where are the downloads?" question unnecessary

Comment: I am not able to find itextpdf.text class anywhere in the itext library. @BrunoLowagie Can you tell me where I can find it. Its not there in the jar I downloaded from maven repository

Comment: `itextpdf.text` isn't a class. It's not even a package name. In iText 5, you had the package `com.itextpdf.text` with different classes such as `Anchor`, `Annotation`, etc. In iText 7, the `text` part was dropped from the package names. Since you don't tell us what you downloaded from Maven, it's unclear what you are asking. Your question is all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can download iText from the Central Repository by adding the following XML snippet to your `pom.xml` if you use Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>${itext.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Source: the official documentation at https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext-java

The current (May 2018) version of iText 5 is 5.5.13.

With this answer, you have also enough information to search on search.maven.org, which will provide you the snippet you need for other build systems like Gradle. You can even download the jar file directly from the Central Repository, although this is not recommended.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly download it from the maven repository

[https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A"com.itextpdf"%20AND%20a%3A"itextpdf"](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.itextpdf%22%20AND%20a%3A%22itextpdf%22)

Comment: Broken link. Please don't post link-only answers.